# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer failed for 2 dataSources

Tags: mysql, spring, configuration, mybatis

Spring 3.2.3 PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer failed to init 2 dataSorces.
For single one it works perfectly, but when I delete comments from the second one "rbmDataSource", it fails.
I can't understand why?

**database.properties file**

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
db.username=root
db.password=
management.db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
management.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_management
management.db.username=root
management.db.password=
```

**Spring applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.db.api" />

    <!-- context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/properties/database.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/-->

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.db.api.dao" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="rbSqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rbSqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"
        name="rbSqlSessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="rbDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rbDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.db.api.management.dao" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="rbmSqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rbmSqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"
        name="rbmSqlSessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="rbmDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rbmDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${management.db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${management.db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${management.db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${management.db.password}" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: What do you mean fails? How it fails?

Comment: the message is 

## Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '${db.driver}'. | 
for single one "rbDataSource" all is OK. and it works good if I enter values manually. without properties file.

Comment: Switch on, please DEBUG for `org.springframework` category. Start your application and show here result logs.

Comment: log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl250yz2ns909ib/db-spring-debug-error.txt

Comment: Check this: http://mbesida.blogspot.com/2013/07/issue-with-mapperscannerconfigurer-in.html